# Retrieve checked checkboxes from array, Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, checkbox

I have simple form:

```
<form action="some_action" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="Data 1"/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="Data 2"/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="Data 3"/>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Values stores in array,

```
$data = new data();
$data->checkboxes = json_encode($request->all());
$data->save();
```

like

```
0 => "Data 1",
1 => "Data 2",
2 => "Data 3"
```

Now, i need to retrieve checkbox state. I passed into view decoded json:

```
$storedCheckboxes = json_decode($data->checkboxes);
return view('some.view')->with('storedCheckboxes', $storedCheckboxes);
```

And try to get it in blade:

```
<input name="data[]" type="checkbox" {{ old('data', $storedCheckboxes->checkboxes[0]) === 'Data 1' ? 'checked' : '' }}/>
```

But i think it's wrong way, because in blade i should hardcode array position. And it works, but only if position present.

Comment: Checkbox state? If it's not checked, it won't be in the request. You're already dealing with an array, just use `in_array()` to see if the key exists.

Comment: Yes. I have 5 checkboxes, and for example, i check only 2. So, i need get state from all of 5. Which from them checked and unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Set index for input name and then use it :

```
@foreach ($datas $key=>$data)

<input name="data[{{$key}}]" type="checkbox" {{old("data[$key])?"checked":''}}/>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Blake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849206/blake)!

I tried to use `in_array()` before, but i confused with parameters. Now clear with it. Works as i need.

```
<input name="data[]" type="checkbox" @if (in_array('Data 1', $storedCheckboxes->checkboxes)) checked="checked" @endif />
<input name="data[]" type="checkbox" @if (in_array('Data 2', $storedCheckboxes->checkboxes)) checked="checked" @endif />
<input name="data[]" type="checkbox" @if (in_array('Data 3', $storedCheckboxes->checkboxes)) checked="checked" @endif />
```

So, i have all checkboxes displayed as i need.